# jQuery not being imported

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to import jquery to work with semantic ui. The problem is, it's giving me a couple of errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at semantic.min.js:11
main.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at main.js:3
```

I know this is telling me jQuery is not being imported but I don't know why. This is my home page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Ttitle</title>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin" rel="stylesheet" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="res/css/frameworks/semantic-ui/semantic.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="res/css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <?php require ROOT_DIR . "views/navs/main_nav.php"; ?>

  <?php
    if(!isset($_GET["section"])):
      require ROOT_DIR . "views/home.php";
    endif;
  ?>

  <!-- IMPORTING JQUERY FROM GOOGLE -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="res/css/frameworks/semantic-ui/semantic.min.js"></script>
  <script src="res/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Any help is appreciated!

*UPDATE*

I tried adding an empty `script` tag before my 3 main tags and somehow it is now being imported. It now looks like this:

```
<!-- IMPORTING JQUERY FROM GOOGLE -->
<script></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="res/css/frameworks/semantic-ui/semantic.min.js"></script>
<script src="res/js/main.js"></script>
```

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: How does the rendered HTML look like. That is what you want to see - also hit F12 and look in the network tab

Comment: Are you sure semantic.min.js in inside the res/css folder?

Comment: For some reason when I go to the network tab it doesn't show jquery being loaded in... The html looks good, it shows my script tag.

Comment: Yeah, I triple checked everything, I even tried to download jquery and import it locally from within my project but still won't work. @Gerard

Comment: Ok. Just seemed it doesn't belong there since there is a js subfolder for the javascript.

Comment: Yeah, it seems kinda odd that they don't divide the js like bootstrap or other frameworks do. Everything in semantic comes in the same folder, CSS and JS. @Gerard

Comment: Looks like it needs to be broken down in steps. The jQuery URL is correct. Try to take the last 2 scripts out and see if it finishes loading.

Comment: Ok, I tried it, removed the 2 last scripts and still didn't load my jquery. Look, this is what is being loaded in:  https://flic.kr/p/UT8JhQ @Gerard

Comment: Last chance, remove the PHP code and try again. Evidently, there's nothing wrong with the CSS.

Comment: Super nooby mistake, I forgot to close a div tag inside my `home.php` which is why it wasn't importing my jquery. Thanks for your help! @Gerard :D

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to close a `div` tag inside my `home.php` file.